# Write permissions not allowed on my USB key

Tags: usb, chmod

I can read/write my USB key normally on Windows XP.
On Ubuntu 12.04 I can only read it.

I tried sudo  to chmod  with 777 my USB key but Ubuntu does not allow me that.

Why this problem happens ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: most probable cause: you mounted it read only. Does it have a button perhaps to make it read only? Important: chmod 777 ... that must show an error if it does not work. what is it?

Answer (score 0):

The device is mounted readonly, which will override any file permissions on the mountpoint or the files on the device. However you are mounting it (manually, automatically, with a daemon, etc) you'll need to adjust the settings to not mount it readonly.